# Getting information from tty Device without using udev Linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, tty

I have a shell script used to identify which serial port a specific product is connected. My problem is that in a specific environment I can't use udev utilities and this broke my script. What is the other alternative to get information from a tty device, like manufacturer, product name, etc.?

**EDIT 1**

My script need to know which specific port a certain product are connected. My device always got a port `ttyACMX`, my job is find out which of those ports my device are connect. The actual script works properly in Linux desktop, the problem is when I run the same script in embedded Linux system, I believe that the udev of `busybox` has limitations.

**EDIT 2**

This is the script used to find the specific port. In desktop system the script works well, but when I run the same script in my specific environment a receive the following error:

> line 9: syntax error: bad substitution

**Script to find serial port**

```
#!/bin/bash

for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); 
    do(syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}";
    devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"; 
    [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]]&& continue; 
    eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)";
    [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && continue;
    temporario=${ID_MODEL,,};
    if [[ $temporario == *"product_name"* || $temporario == *"company"* ]];
         then echo "/dev/$devname";
    fi);
    done;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to be notified when a given product is plugged in or to what port is it plugged into? What system is that? Does it have `mdev`? You can always read `netlink` events on your own as shown here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/pending/hotplug.txt. Is `RS-232->USB` adapter used by any chance?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, I'll try to implement these suggestions. I did an update on my post to explain better my question.

Comment: `busybox` does not have `udev` - it has `mdev` as I mentioned.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk , In this case I don't have `mdev` too.